# Are invoices traceable internationally?

Tags: billing

I'm a software developer in Buenos Aires. I will be billing a company in the UK.

I can make electronic invoices (in the Argentina's IRS equivalent web page) or pre-printed invoices filled by hand, that do not need to be presented to IRS or at least in a wide time window (months).

So my question is, when I invoice a company in another country, can I use a pre-printed paper invoice?  Or is there some particular form or electronic document that I would need to use to comply with their reporting requirements?

Comment: Please edit the title for a more accurate description, I don' t know how to title my question

Comment: This isn't a personal finance question

Comment: I think if you reworded it "invoices" that would make more sense. When I first read it, I thought you meant dollar bills.

Comment: We've generally interpreted personal finance to include self-employed folks, and I think that this is a question from that point of view.

Comment: @JorgeeFG I edited your question to be perhaps more clear and seem a bit more on-topic; if that doesn't make sense let me know.  I would edit the title but I'm not 100% sure what to edit it to.

Answer (score 1):

How you invoice is typically up to you and the company you are invoicing.  When I've done it in the past, I've typically written up my own form, and had no issue; this is in the US, where there's no reporting requirement similar to what you may be describing.

That said, it is something you should typically clarify during the contract negotiation phase.  If the company you will be invoicing has particular requirements (whether for reporting purposes or their own internal reasons), they should mention that during that discussion.